# Is there a Python equivalent to the mahalanobis() function in R? If not, how can I implement it?

Tags: python, r, mahalanobis

I have the following code in R that calculates the mahalanobis distance on the Iris dataset and returns a numeric vector with 150 values, one for every observation in the dataset.

```
x=read.csv("Iris Data.csv")
mean<-colMeans(x)
Sx<-cov(x)
D2<-mahalanobis(x,mean,Sx)
```

I tried to implement the same in Python using 'scipy.spatial.distance.mahalanobis(u, v, VI)' function, but it seems this function takes only one-dimensional arrays as parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the Iris dataset from R, I suppose it is the same you are using.

First, these is my R benchmark, for comparison:

```
x <- read.csv("IrisData.csv")
x <- x[,c(2,3,4,5)]
mean<-colMeans(x)
Sx<-cov(x)
D2<-mahalanobis(x,mean,Sx)
```

Then, in python you can use:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import mahalanobis
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_csv('IrisData.csv')
x = x.ix[:,1:]

Sx = x.cov().values
Sx = sp.linalg.inv(Sx)

mean = x.mean().values

def mahalanobisR(X,meanCol,IC):
    m = []
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        m.append(mahalanobis(X.iloc[i,:],meanCol,IC) ** 2)
    return(m)

mR = mahalanobisR(x,mean,Sx)
```

I defined a function so you can use it in other sets, (observe I use pandas DataFrames as inputs)

Comparing results:

In R

```
> D2[c(1,2,3,4,5)]

[1] 2.134468 2.849119 2.081339 2.452382 2.462155
```

In Python:

```
In [43]: mR[0:5]
Out[45]: 
[2.1344679233248431,
 2.8491186861585733,
 2.0813386639577991,
 2.4523816316796712,
 2.4621545347140477]
```

Just be careful that what you get in R is the squared Mahalanobis distance.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not really well versed with Python yet so I was struggling over it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Could you also suggest how to use the Mahalanobis distances to perform outlier detection? How can we decide upon the threshold value of the distances in order to detect outliers?

Comment: You could use the $(1- \alpha)$ percentile of a $\chi^2$ distribution as a threshold. See here for a (very much!) descriptive answer about statistical aspects of Mahalanobis distance: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance

Comment: Note: `df.ix` is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) and should be replaced with `df.iloc`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBoles I just edited the post to reflect that change.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

x = ...

mean = x.mean(axis=0).reshape(1, -1)  # make sure 2D
vi = np.linalg.inv(np.cov(x.T))

cdist(mean, x, 'mahalanobis', VI=vi)
```